# JS как из массива вытащить ассоциативный массив у которого значение ключа определенное слово?

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты, foreach

```
products: [
    { id: 1, name: "Апельсины", price: 1000, amount: 30, category: "fruit" },
    { id: 2, name: "Бананы", price: 1000, amount: 30, category: "fruit" },
    { id: 3, name: "Помидоры", price: 2000, amount: 10, category: "vegetable" }
]
```

как мне при выводе проверить элементы у которых ключ с значением "fruit" ?

Comment: `сonsole.log(products.filter(item=>item.category === 'fruit'))`

Answer (score 0):

ответ на основе комментария Node_pro, чтобы закрыть вопрос.

```js
const PRODUCTS = [
    { id: 1, name: "Апельсины", price: 1000, amount: 30, category: "fruit" },
    { id: 2, name: "Бананы", price: 1000, amount: 30, category: "fruit" },
    { id: 3, name: "Помидоры", price: 2000, amount: 10, category: "vegetable" }
];

console.log(PRODUCTS.filter(item => item.category === "fruit"));
```